# Why is my map function in React giving me an error? (...is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a prop from one component(App.js) to another (list.js). I keep getting an error that says my map function is not a function inside list.js. I am using map to iterate through an array of objects and grab the value from keys. The parent component App.js works and displays the list of elements from its map function. Inside App.js I made a prop called 'card' in the List component that is supposed to contain the value of the second array of objects in my STORE file. What am I doing wrong here? In my components tab in the browser I can see the array of objects listed from a console.log. The prop 'store' in App.js contains the the data from my STORE.js file.

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import List from "./list";
import "./app.css";

function App(props) {
  return (
    <main className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Trelloyes!</h1>
      </header>
      {props.store.lists.map((list) => {
        return (
          <List
            key={list.id}
            header={list.header}
            card={props.store.allCards}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

list.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./card";

function List(props) {
  console.log(props.card);
  return (
    <div className="App-list">
      <section className="List">
        <header className="List-header">
          <h2>{props.header}</h2>
          <div className="List-cards">
            {props.card.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Card id={item.id} title={item.title} content={item.content} />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </header>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}

export default List;
```

STORE.js:

```
const STORE = {
  lists: [
    {
      id: "1",
      header: "First list",
      cardIds: ["a", "b", "e", "f", "g", "j", "l", "m"],
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      header: "Second list",
      cardIds: ["b", "c", "d", "f", "h", "i", "k"],
    },
    {
      id: "3",
      header: "Third list",
      cardIds: [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e",
        "f",
        "g",
        "h",
        "i",
        "j",
        "k",
        "l",
        "m",
      ],
    },
    {
      id: "4",
      header: "Fourth list",
      cardIds: ["l", "m"],
    },
  ],
  allCards: {
    a: { id: "a", title: "First card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    b: { id: "b", title: "Second card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    c: { id: "c", title: "Third card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    d: { id: "d", title: "Fourth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    e: { id: "e", title: "Fifth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    f: { id: "f", title: "Sixth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    g: { id: "g", title: "Seventh card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    h: { id: "h", title: "Eighth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    i: { id: "i", title: "Ninth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    j: { id: "j", title: "Tenth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    k: { id: "k", title: "Eleventh card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    l: { id: "l", title: "Twelfth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
    m: { id: "m", title: "Thirteenth card", content: "lorem ipsum" },
  },
};

export default STORE;
```

Comment: is it `props.card.map` that throws the error? is `props.card` an Array?

Comment: Yes it is props.card.map that is throwing the error, and I just now realized after looking at this for hours that allCards or props.card is actually an Object with nested Objects. Not quite sure how to go about getting the values.

Comment: `Object.values(props.card)` will give you the values

Comment: Okay word. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your card object to an array in order to use the map function available for Arrays.

Try the following for your Card component:

```
import React from "react";

function Card(props) {
   return (
       <div key={props.id}>
           <h1>{props.title}</h1>
           <p>{props.content}</p>
       </div>
   )
}

function List(props) {
  console.log(Array.isArray(props.card) ? "true": "false");
  return (
    <div className="App-list">
      <section className="List">
        <header className="List-header">
          <h2>{props.header}</h2>
          <div className="List-cards">
            {Object.entries(props.card).map((item) => {
                console.log('item', item);
              return (
                <Card key={item[1].id} id={item[1].id} title={item[1].title} content={item[1].content} />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </header>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}


export default List;
```

References:

JavaScript Tutorial Website. Convert an Object to an Array in JavaScript. https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/convert-an-object-to-an-array-in-javascript/. (Accessed November 22, 2020)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe props of App.js do not have store. Have you passed store data from parent of App.js?

Or try this:

```js
import React from "react";
import List from "./list";
import "./app.css";
import STORE from "[path to your STORE.js]"

function App(props) {
  return (
    <main className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>Trelloyes!</h1>
      </header>
      {STORE.lists.map((list) => {
        return (
          <List
            key={list.id}
            header={list.header}
            card={props.store.allCards}
          />
        );
      })}
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your map works before load so it may occurs error
so check with those

```
props && props.card && props.card.map...

props && props.store && props.store.lists && props.store.lists.map...
```